# What does "Strips nonglobal symbols but saves external symbols" mean in practice?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

I'm looking at an Xcode project that has set the `Strip Linked Product` to `YES` and `Strip Style` to `Non-Global Symbols`.

[Apple's developer doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) states that this strip style "Strips nonglobal symbols but saves external symbols". What does this really mean?

It seems as though if I have the following:

```
// Foo.h
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (void)doSomething;
@end

// Foo.m
@implementation Foo
- (void)doSomething { NSLog(@"Something"); }
@end
```

If I compile this as part of a framework, I could in a separate project include this framework and add the following to it:

```
// MyFoo.h
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (void)doSomething;
@end

// MyFoo.m
@implementation Foo
- (void)doSomething { NSLog(@"Something else"); }
@end
```

I could compile without symbols clashing and run, if I understand this correctly. So how does this work?

Comment: That won't work. No amount of linker-level symbol stripping will completely avoid the runtime collision between two Objective-C classes with the same name.

Comment: I'm looking at it work, specifically compiling a version of SBJson into a framework, including that framework, then compiling a new version of SBJson on top of it. My only thought would be that because the compiler knows that the SBJson files are mean to be framework private that it can strip the symbols.